# Replacing an ImageButton with a styled icon

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I need to replace an `ImageButton` in a `GridView` `ItemTemplate` with an icon that is in a CSS style.

Ordinarily I would do this by replacing the ImageButton with a hidden button and then call some JQuery to click the hidden button. Something like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="#" onclick="Utils.ClickButton('<%= btnTest.ClientID %>');"><i class="icon">&nbsp;</i>Download to Excel</a>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" CssClass="btn" ToolTip="Download to Excel" runat="server" />
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with the ImageButtons that have a command argument to put the grid into edit mode. If I implement the above I get a runtime error saying that btnTest can't be found.

So what I need is:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                                ImageUrl="/images/delete.png" />
```

To look like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="#" onclick="Utils.ClickButton('<%= btnTest.ClientID %>');"><i class="icon">&nbsp;</i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with LinkButton

`<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CssClass="btn">
     <i class="icon">&nbsp;</i>
</asp:LinkButton>`

And you can handle the LinkButton click in GridView's RowCommand event

```
protected void gvList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
       //Handle Delete Command
    }                     
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend the use of Eval, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623516/The-Evil-of-Eval-in-ASP-NET) is why!

Comment: Eval has been banished :-)